# Google Chrome Extension to submit POST/GET requests?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

As a developer I sometimes need to be able to make GET/POST requests without having a form on the page. Are there any plug-ins that allow me to submit GET/POST requests to a specified page and then see the results?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Simple REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhjcajmcbmldlhcimfajhfbgofnpcjmb). No frills, gets the job done.

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but how do i write a POST request? Can you link me to a tutorial or a manual or something?

Comment: @qwerty It depends on the web application, doesn't it? Look for the webapp's API docs.

Comment: Does it really? How does the browser tell which webapp is running on the server before it submits the HTTP request? And what exactly do you mean by "webapp", i don't quite get what you're saying.

Comment: @qwerty I'm not sure what you're asking either, but you can take a look at this. http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but that link helped! Though i found a plugin for firefox that was even easier to use, it's called UrlParams. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @qwerty: if you are using firefox, Live HttpHeader is a good choice.

Comment: This is great if you want to log on to the server using your regular user friendly login form then post some stuff as that user. by contrast, Postman requires you to craft an authentication, know which type of authentication is used and enter the token details and what not.

Comment: The link does not work anymore

Answer (score 28):

You can try [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm).

It works good for making HTTP requests and debugging and I like its UI.

[image]

Comment: How can we [stop the automatic `Accept-Encoding`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome#comment43279634_9716192) headers?

Answer (score 5):

### [DHC - Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm)

"REST & HTTP API developer's pocket knife. Easy to use and configurable. HATEOAS, Hypermedia, Requests History+Repository, and more."

I find it very useful and it has many features.[image: DHC Snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

[XHR Poster](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akdbimilobjkfhgamdhneckaifceicen) is great, lets you save some requests, and shows the response nicely formatted.  The results panel is tabbed so you can see many results after doing new requests.

Comment: The link does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

**Spy plugin for Chrome**

screenshot:
[image]

It shows you all requests on website, allows to edit and send GET,POST,PUT,PATCH requests.
You can see a animated promotional page at the Chrome Web Store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spy/aedipmheomnpcbgmanofhaccebgapije?hl=en).